# Which western pilots trained on the Buran?

Tags: buran

At least one western pilot (Jean-Loup Chrétien) trained to pilot the Buran.

Did any other non-soviet pilots train for this shuttle?

Comment: That is a fascinating fact!  Do you have a reference, I'd love to read more.  I worked with Jean-Loup, I wish I had asked him about this!

Comment: It's listed e.g. in https://www.jsc.nasa.gov/history/oral_histories/ChretienJL/ChretienJL_5-8-02.htm  Lists like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buran_programme#Flight_crew_preparation don't mention him though.

Comment: @Hobbes that oral history link was great.  Thanks.

Comment: @OrganicMarble https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=fRjKKfzdRlo sorry it's a French documentary. You can see him flying a mig with air brakes and gear down to simulate the Buran approach.

Comment: They still have the Buran simulator in the ISS mockup hall in Star City, I saw it when I visited. If I were a millionaire I could probably get them to train me in it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the info from http://www.buran.ru/htm/pilots.htm, only four Frenchman were trained for Buran.

- Jean-Loup Chrétien
- Michel Tognini

> During his stay in Russia, Tognini also gained piloting experience of BURAN simulators (MiG-25, Tupolev 154). (c) [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michel_Tognini)

- Philippe Perrin
- Benoit Silve

Comment: Interesting. Chrétien, Perrin, and Tognini would go on to fly on the Shuttle.

Comment: So no western non french mens ?

Answer (score 4):

From the book [Energiya-Buran; the Soviet Space Shuttle](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387698489) (by Hendrickx and Vis) (page 222):

> Finally, in the early 1990s French 'spationauts' Jean-Loup Chrétien, Michel Tognini, and Leopold Eyharts flew both the Tupolev Tu-154LL and MiG-25 Buran training aircraft in preparation for the European Hermes spaceplane program. There are no indications that they were considered to fly aboard Buran itself.

No other non-Soviets are listed as Buran candidates in this book.

Comment: Eyharts also flew on the Shuttle. Buran training seems like a good career move.